# Jquery appending HTML at index 1 in select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

**selectBox HTML**

```
<select id="customerBox" onchange="customerOperation(this);">
    <option value="-1"  > Select</option>
    <option value="delete"  class="delete-operation"> Delete </option>
    <option value="add" class="add-operation"> Add </option>
</select>
```

I have two links  i.e link1 and link2.

On click of link1 , i need to remove the delete option
On click of link2 , need to attach it again

on click of link 1 i am detaching the html like below

```
 var deleteOptionHtml = $("#customerBox option[class=delete-operation]").detach();
```

on click of link 2 i am reattaching the html like below

```
  $("#customerBox").append(deleteOptionHtml);
```

Everything workfine but  delete option gets appended after Add and i see the options order as `Select,Add, Delete` instead of `Select,Delete,Add`.
Is there a way i can append the  html(delete option) at the 1 index

**Note:-** I am not using jquery show/hide function becoz thats does  not work in browser like IE/chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/):

```
$("#customerBox").prepend(deleteOptionHtml);
```

---

To always insert it before the add option, use this:

```
$("#customerBox option.add-operation").before(deleteOptionHtml);
```

Comment: I actually missed one point in my question.Modified it. See if you can help. (Your answer was great as per my previous question) but i am not getting how to append it after select

Comment: can i specify i want to append after specific selector?